# Does CDN for static content in Magento 2 is Secure?

Tags: magento2

**I am using Magento 2 CDN,**

for media, as much as I know is working well,

But compare to Magento 1, Magento 2 static files are different things.

> does CDN for static content is secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely use a CDN for magento 2 without risk of the site breaking unless of course the unlikely event the CDN goes down

For example you can use fastly for static assets

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/cdn/configure-fastly.html

For a small site will cost around 50 dollars a month. Is available on open source. Check extension on magento marketplace.

https://marketplace.magento.com/fastly-magento2.html